# Google load jQuery and jQueryUI

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jquery) to load jQuery for some pages and jQuery UI for others.
On the pages where I just need jQuery, I do the following:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnLoad() {
    // my jQuery goodness
}
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

And on the pages where I need jQueryUI, I also add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Library/jQuery/UI/Smoothness/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnLoadUI(){
    $('div.tabs').tabs();
    $('input.date').datepicker();
}
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoadUI);
</script>
```

Q: Am I doing anything wrong?  It's working, but I want to know if I'm writing code that doesn't make sense.
Q: Does Google have the various UI css themes?  Or am I right in thinking that I need to serve up the smoothness theme myself?  (It's not really a custom theme - it's just the default one).

Comment: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/10/jquery-ui-1-9-0/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks fine to me. I'm just going to assume that Google does things properly so that jQuery UI could never possibly load before jQuery, which is what the [Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#jqueryUI) seems to suggest.

<del>Google does not host the themes, no. You'll need to get them from the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) website and host them yourself.</del>

**EDIT:** I take it back. See [this blog post](http://encosia.com/2009/10/11/do-you-know-about-this-undocumented-google-cdn-feature/) for the Google CDN links for the post popular themes. I never knew that!

So, to answer your question: you are doing everything right - except for this secret, undocumented list of CSS files. Okay - keep up the good work!

Comment: I think I'll use
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

Thanks Matchu for your words of encouragement!

Comment: Ah google saves the day again. I was having trouble with my local themes, now I can just use their CDN instead.